# Migrating from big to little endian: How to predetermine problematic code?

Tags: c, static-analysis, portability

I am about to migrate a small project of C code (30+ kSLOC) from a 32-bit big to a 32-bit little endian platform.  I would like to check ante festum, how much work this will be, so I would like to spot code that relies on the original endianess.

I am looking for an as comprehensive as possible collection of C code idioms, which are depending on big endian.  Do not bother with the effort needed to detect the use of such idioms in real code, I have some code analysis tool support available.

Comment: unions, bitmasks, network traffic, direct hardware accesses are mostly problematic

Comment: @paladin bitmaks are not problematic. Endianess have no effect on that.

Comment: @stevesummit could you give me an example? I mean for example, (n & 0x300) will always give you the 2 lowest bit on the second byte, regarldess of endian or how it's stored.

Comment: C bitwise operators abstract away endianess.

Comment: Network code is not a problem if it uses proper net-to-host and host-to-net functions.

Comment: @Fredrik Sorry, I was thinking about bit*fields*, which is what I suspect paladin meant also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to look out for:

- Fishy pointer casts and fishy type conversions between integer types of different sizes. These may also be latent alignment or strict aliasing bugs.
- Serialization/de-serialization code, where data is read from/written to byte arrays.
- Data communication interfaces *without* serialization/de-serialization code. That is: CPU just happened to have same endianess as the network, which is common for big endian systems in particular. Ethernet, CAN, UART and so on.
- Structs with bit-fields.
- Union type punning.

Comment: Thanks, Lundin.  I'll start out with reviewing the uses of casts, unions and bit-fields.